# How to update query from jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to insert data to database by query in JSP. Here is my code

```
<%@ include file="connect.jsp" %>
<%
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/travDB.accdb"));
    Statement st = con.createStatement(1004,1008);
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String konf = request.getParameter("konf");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
    String tribe = request.getParameter("tribe");
    String start = request.getParameter("start");
    String agree = request.getParameter("agree");
    String temp = "";

        query = "insert into msuser (username, password, email, tribe, starting position, population) values ('"+user+"','"+pass+"','"+phone+"','"+tribe+"','"+temp+"',0)";
        st.executeUpdate(query);

        response.sendRedirect("Register.jsp?err=0");

    }

%>
```

Why it said

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /JSP_H2Soal2_T213/doRegis.jsp at line 82
82:         st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: if I wrapped st.executeUpdate(query); with try catch, it isn't error but query didn't inserted :(

Comment: `insert into msuser (username, password, email, tribe, starting position, population)`.. _starting position_ has a space in it, usually column names did not have spaces..

Comment: @Asif yap, so I get last index of userid (set as autonumber) and input it manually because of starting position.

Comment: @Asif Yes, that's the answer!

Comment: Be careful, your code seems vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: You might want to upvote and accept correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't perform database updates in JSP -- do this in your business layer (servlets).

You should only use JSP for presentation.

However, this is not the cause of the exception. You will need to examine the full stacktrace from the exception (Again, this is easier if you can log it from a servlet class). Without that, it is impossible to know what the problem is.

Other people have experienced the same problem, see:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1552551
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/170609-mysql-posting-errors-with-jsp/

**EDIT**

Asif's comment may solve your problem: In your query, you have a column name that contains a space. Column names with spaces are problematic. Check the escape syntax for your DBMS -- or, if you can, change the column name to something without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

[executeUpdate returns an int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29).

Try the following changes:

```
int result;
result = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<sql:update>
    UPDATE table_name
    SET column_name = new_value, column_name1 = new_value1
    WHERE column_name = some_value
</sql:update>
```

Tried and tested, works 100%